# How to change mail "from" name for Fail2Ban email notifications?

Tags: centos, fail2ban

I have Fail2Ban sending me emails from various servers but I can't tell at a glance which server because the email "from" name is always just "Fail2Ban".

I've managed to set the "from" address differently for each server but I still have to open the email to see this value. I would prefer it if I could alter the "from" name for each server's Fail2Ban installation so that I can tell at a glance which server it's from.

EDIT - to be more clear. Currently I'm getting this:

```
Fail2ban<fail2ban.myserver@example.com>
```

I want this:

```
Fail2ban.myserver<fail2ban.myserver@example.com>
```

Comment: Your local mailserver should append the hostname to the user name `fail2ban`, so from results in `fail2ban@example.com`.

Comment: You've misunderstood. I've edited the question to explain better (I hope).

Comment: It should be changed in your actions which sends email (directory action.d for example). Check for actionban in action.d/mail.conf

Comment: Yep, change the action in `jail.conf`: Adapt the sendmail parameters in `action_mwl` or whatever the variable is called.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate @sebix answer above, you need to modify `sendername` variable in `jail.conf`. For example

```
sendername = Fail2ban.myserver
```

Or you can replace 'myserver' with `hostname -f` so you don't need to hardcode the server name in configuration file in each server

```
sendername = Fail2ban.`hostname -f`
```